# ConcurrentModificationException while I'm trying to add an item to a collection

Tags: java, android

I've spend all day trying to solve this issue. I try to use itertaion? synchronization, and a lot of other shamanic methods but all the time i'am getting ConcurrentModificationException.Here the code.

```
package com.androidgui.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomView extends SurfaceView implements Callback {
    private UpdateThread thread;
    private AButton btn;
    private AWindow wnd;
    private ArrayList<AControl> globalControls;
    private Object sync;
    public static int posX;
    public static int posY;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        this.LoadResourse();
        sync =  new Object();
        this.globalControls = new ArrayList<AControl>();
        btn = new AButton(10, 10,null,AControl.InterfaceImages.Button); 
        this.globalControls.add(btn);
        wnd = new AWindow(10, 10, 200, 100, null);
        this.SetDelegates();

    }
    private void LoadResourse()
    {
        AControl.InterfaceImages.Button = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.button);
    }
    private void SetDelegates()
    {
        btn.setEventHandler(new EventHandler() {

            @Override
            public void ProcessEvent() {
                synchronized (sync) {
                    globalControls.add(wnd);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        posX = (this.getWidth()- AControl.InterfaceImages.Button.getWidth()) /2;
        posY = (this.getHeight()- AControl.InterfaceImages.Button.getHeight()) /2;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        thread = new UpdateThread(this.getHolder(), this);
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        thread.setRunning(false);
        boolean _retry=true;
        try
        {
        while(_retry)
        {
            thread.join();
            _retry=false;
        }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        synchronized (sync) {
            for(AControl item :this.globalControls)
                item.onClick(event);
        }

        return true;
    }
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        synchronized (sync) {   
        ArrayList<AControl> temp  = (ArrayList<AControl>) this.globalControls.clone();
            for(AControl item :temp)
                item.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cloned your list in here:

```
 public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        synchronized (sync) {   
        ArrayList<AControl> temp  = (ArrayList<AControl>) this.globalControls.clone();
            for(AControl item :temp)
                item.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
```

But not in the method before it:

```
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        synchronized (sync) {
            for(AControl item :this.globalControls)
                item.onClick(event);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I'd say that's the problem. But the fact that you didn't include the stack trace make it harder to guess. Adding synchronization won't fix your issue, as the problem is that you are likely modifying a list while traversing it.

Answer (score 1):

All that the ConcurrentModificationException means is that whilst iterating over the collection using an iterator or enhanced for loop your tried to add or remove an element from the collection.

eg

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("some string");
for (String str : list) {
    list.remove(str); // will throw a ConcurrentModificationException
}
```

In your code it seems that your delegate method for button in your globalControls list is is getting invoked whilst you are iterating over the list (That is, `item.onClick` and `item.onDraw` will invoke the EventHandler you have written. I noticed that you are synchronising on the list, this won't help you in this situation as it is the same thread that is accessing the list.

As Ravi mentioned earlier it is because you do not copy your List before iterating over it (in `onTouchEvent`) that the ConcurrentModificationException is being thrown. Make sure you copy the list before iterating over it!

As a side not you should only synchronise for the shortest possible time that you have to.

That is instead of

```
synchronized (sync) {   
    ArrayList<AControl> temp  = (ArrayList<AControl>) this.globalControls.clone();
        for(AControl item :temp) {
            item.onDraw(canvas);
        }
}
```

You should write

```
ArrayList<AControl> copy;
synchronized (sync) {   
    copy = (ArrayList<AControl>) globalControls.clone();
    // exit synchronised block as we no longer need to be synchronised 
    // as we have a copy of the list now
}

for(AControl item : copy) {
    item.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify to a collection while iterating it (from the same or from another thread)

You either need to make a copy that you iterate (`new ArrayList<>(existingList)`) or use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`